# Downloads folder shows Access Denied icon

Tags: finder, macos, security, permission, filesystem

Starting this morning Chrome, Safari et all started showing my `~/Downloads` with an access denied icon. Finder does **not** show this icon. I suspect this is something Code42 CrashPlan did overnight (it's a work issued MBP with some pre-installed apps). Now, the question is, how do I make my downloads again available?

- adding read/write myself and everyone via `chmod +ai`
- adding read/write myself and everyone via Finder -> file -> Get Info

`ls -el` shows that `~/Downloads` is missing some attributes compared to other folders like `~/Documents`:

```
drwx---rwx+  6 xx  yy   204 Jan 11 19:15 Documents
 0: XX-AE59E7573812 allow list,add_file,search,add_subdirectory,delete_child,readattr,writeattr,readextattr,writeextattr,readsecurity
drwx---rwx+ 25 xx  yy   850 Jan 27 08:35 Downloads
 0: user:xx inherited allow list,add_file,delete
 1: group:everyone inherited allow list,add_file,delete
 2: group:owner inherited allow list,add_file,delete
drwx---rwx@ 51 xx  yy  1734 Jan 24 16:41 Library
 0: XX-AE59E7573812 allow list,add_file,search,add_subdirectory,delete_child,readattr,writeattr,readextattr,writeextattr,readsecurity
```

The existing ACLs on `~/Downloads` are the one I added myself. Still, the browsers show it as Access Denied. Attempt to save a download fails silently (no error, but no file either).

[image]

OS X El Capitan 10.11.6

Comment: I tried to change "The existing ACLs on /~Downloads" to "...~/Downloads" but Ask Different won't let me because edits must be at least 6 characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure this is *your* Downloads folder. Click the little upside-down carat next to the "Save As" text field to see an expanded window, press Command-Shift-H to go to your Home folder and then see if the Downloads folder there is still inaccessible.

Comment: Also, what's the result of "ls -el" in /Users/...since the permissions are inherited, let's see what they are inheriting.

Comment: `Make sure this is your Downloads folder` D'oh, that was it!

Comment: glad it was a simple solution. You might want to reset the permissions that you changed while trying to work on this problem.